# From gearing range to gears ratio

Tags: internally-geared-hub

been looking at internal gears and I have a question.
When I looked at [Alfine 11](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alfine-s7000s700/SG-S7001-11.html), it shows both the ratio of every gear, for example, "Gear ratio 1: 0.527", and also the total range.
However, for other hubs, like [Kindernay](https://kindernay.com/products/complete-gear-hub/product-landing-kindernay-xiv/), they only give the range ("543% with unique intervals").

Is there a way to know what would be the individual gear ratios in that case?

Comment: As you know the gear jumps are equal 13-point-something percent, a little maths will get us there. Probably someone else will do this before me but it's a good excercise

Answer (score 2):

This is a math problem. The Kindernay claims to have consistent steps of 13.9%. If you knew what at least one ratio was, you could work from there to figure out what the rest of the ratios are, but without knowing that, there's no way to "anchor" that range.

However, the Kindernay FAQ does get specific:

> The numerical ratios on the Kindernay XIV from 1 through 14 are as follows: 1: 0.272 2: 0.309 3: 0.353 4: 0.402 5: 0.458 6: 0.521 7: 0.594 8: 0.676 9: 0.770 10: 0.878 11: 1.000 12: 1.138 13: 1.297 14: 1.477 Total range/span: 543%.
> The numerical ratios on The Kindernay VII from 1 through 7 is as follows: 1: 0.484 2: 0.616 3: 0.785 4: 1.000 5: 1.274 6: 1.623 7: 2.068 Total range/span: 428%.

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I was missing (: I would have expected to find it in the same page. but thanks.